# How do i overlay a text box over a native camera view in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, camera, native

Having trouble carrying out a build I am trying to complete.

I have the build 1 and build 2 complete.

Build 1 - A simple blank screen with two text boxes with alignment constraints

Build 2 - When application is run it calls the native back camera of an IOS device.

My third build is these two previous builds together as one, where the native camera shows a live video feed and over layed is the two text boxes with their alignment constraints.

I am unsure how to bring the two bits of code together.

The code i currently have:

Build 1 - .h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *TestTextBox;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *TestTetBox2;

@end
```

Build 1 - .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController

@synthesize TestTextBox;

@synthesize TestTetBox2;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Build 2 - .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;


@end
```

Build 2 - .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.imageView.image == nil) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; //Defualts to Native Camera View
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO; //removes camera controlls
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    else{

    }

}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot present the camera in a custom `UIView` using the `UIImagePickerController`. You need to use `AVFoundation` framework to present a camera in a custom `UIView`.

Comment: ok cool!! are you aware of how I can go about correcting this ?

Comment: pls follow https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/

Comment: thank! just had a read though that, so my next steps would be to use this code from here. 

would i put it into the ViewController.swift or the AppDelegate.swift ?

Im not needing to use the Focus or colour balance features, so can i follow it up to the end of the setup section?

Comment: what u need is ismply setup a preview layer and start camera session in that layer

Comment: ahhh right, ok cool, that makes sense, i advent used swift before, I've only used objective c.

where should i be putting this code in my xcode project? 

I'm a novice at this so need it in very clear cut simple terms to understand